# PYSPARK : How to covert SQL query with multiple case statements to Pyspark/Pyspark-SQL?

Tags: sql, database, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two set of queries with multiple case statements. I need to achieve the same logic in pyspark. I tried but I'm facing some difficulties with multiple when. Any help would be appreciatable.

**FIRST QUERY**

```
case
when appointment_date is null
then 0
when resolution_desc in (
'CSTXCL - OK BY PHONE'
)
or resolution_des ilike '%NO VAN ROLL%'
then 0
when status in ('PENDING','CANCELLED')
then 0
when ticket_type = 'install'
and appointment_required is true
end as truck_roll
```

**SECOND QUERY**

```
case when status = 'COMPLETED'  and resolution not in ('CANCELLING ORDER','CANCEL ORDER')
then 1 else 0 end as completed, 
case when status = 'CANCELLED'  or ( status in ('COMPLETED','PENDING' ) and resolution_desc in ('CANCELLING ORDER','CANCEL ORDER') ) then 1 else 0 end as cancelled.
```

**I tried the below code for second query but not working:**

```
sparkdf.withColumn('completed', f.when((sparkdf.ticket_status =='COMPLETED') & (~sparkdf.resolution_description.isin('CANCELLING ORDER','CANCEL ORDER','CLOSE SRO')),1).otherwise(0))\
.withColumn('cancelled', f.when((sparkdf.ticket_status == 'CANCELLED') | (sparkdf.ticket_status.isin('COMPLETED','PENDING')) & (sparkdf.resolution_description.isin('CANCELLING ORDER','CANCEL ORDER','CLOSE SRO')),1).otherwise(0))
```

Comment: You'll have easier time registering your dataframe as sql view and running the same, slightly adjusted sql code against this view. To register use: `df.createOrReplaceTempView('df_view')`, to use sql use: `df = spark.sql('''your_sql_query from df_view''')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of "expr" function to execute SQL code (in this case with triple quotes because it is multi-line):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

sparkdf.withColumn(
    'completed',
    expr('''
           CASE WHEN status = 'COMPLETED' 
                  AND resolution NOT IN ('CANCELLING ORDER',
                                         'CANCEL ORDER') THEN 1 
                ELSE                                          0 
           END
         '''
        )
)
```

Of course, you would do the same for the "cancelled" column